# JSON mapping to object with field of generic type with FasterXML

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

I need to parse json, which looks like this

```
{
    "ReturnedObject": {object_of_various_type},
    "Status": "Some string",
    "Success": true,
    "Message": "some string"
}
```

where ReturnedObject can be object of various type. Usualy I use [Faster XML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) for mapping to object and I would like to use this library for this also.

ReturnedObject is object of various type. I know the type of this object, but I don't know, how to tell FasterXML library, that ReturnedObject is this type and it should map it to that.

I tried to make ResponseObject generic, but I don't know, how or if it is even possible to pass `.class` with this generic parameter.

I'm not event sure, if it's even possible to have class with multiple fields of all types I can get in json, because I don't know, how to tell to FasterXML proper type of ReturnedObject.

I would like to avoid creating class for every ReturnedObject, which holds my Object.

Thank you for your advice and time.

**EDIT**

**I found the solution**

For anyone looking for complete example, here it is.

Method to parse, where `Class<T> clazz` is class for generic type, `ResponseObject.class` is class for whole json (example of json is up)

```
public static <T> ResponseObject<T> parse(String json, Class<T> clazz) {
    initialize();
    JsonParser jp;
    ResponseObject<T> obj = null;
    try {
        jp = jsonFactory.createParser(json);
        // THIS IS IMPORTANT PART FOR MAPPING
        JavaType type = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(ResponseObject.class, clazz);
        obj = objectMapper.readValue(json, type);
        // 
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return obj;
}
```

ResponseObject class looks like this

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class ResponseObject<T> {
    String status;
    boolean success;
    String message;
    T returnedObject;

    /**
    * get and set methods for status, success, message
    */

    public T getReturnedObject() {
       return returnedObject;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ReturnedObject")
    public void setReturnedObject(T retudnedObject) {
        this.returnedObject = retudnedObject;
    }

}
```